# Not able to create array of object in java

Tags: java

```
public class 1
{ int a ; 
int b ;
int c ;
 } 

public class 2 {
int d ;
int e;
}
```

These are my two classes.
How can I declare an array in class 1 which can hold the objects of class 2.
Basically I want 
print (int a ,int b ,int c ,array[d ,e] ) kind of thing..
I am a newbie in java :)

Comment: so what is the problem create an array of class `Two` type in class `One`

Comment: A number isn't a valid class name according to the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html).

Comment: Keep a letter before the class name say, `public class a1` and `public class a2`

Answer (score 0):

In java identifiers cannot be numbers, so I renamed your classes:

```
public class Class1 {
    int a ; 
    int b ;
    int c ;
    Class2[] array;
} 

public class Class2 {
    int d ;
    int e;
}
```